# Orbeon forms generates duplicate tags

Tags: xml, forms, orbeon

I'm trying to create a form in orbeon forms (4.10 PE) with a repeated grid. I would like to fill this form using a request parameter. However, it seems that when I use xf:insert to replace the main data instance, the xml is somehow transformed.

I have the following minimal form published as test/test at http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/test/test :

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
     xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
     xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
     xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
     xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
     xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
     xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder">;
<xh:head>
    <xh:title>Untitled Form</xh:title>
    <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">

        <!-- Main instance -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <form>
                <section-1>
                    <control-1/>
                    <mygrid>
                        <mygrid-iteration>
                            <control-5/>
                            <control-6/>
                        </mygrid-iteration>
                        <mygrid-iteration>
                            <control-5/>
                            <control-6/>
                        </mygrid-iteration>
                    </mygrid>
                </section-1>
            </form>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Bindings -->
        <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
            <xf:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">
                <xf:bind id="control-1-bind" name="control-1" ref="control-1"/>
                <xf:bind id="mygrid-bind" ref="mygrid" name="mygrid">
                    <xf:bind id="mygrid-iteration-bind" ref="mygrid-iteration" name="mygrid-iteration">
                        <xf:bind id="control-5-bind" ref="control-5" name="control-5"/>
                        <xf:bind id="control-6-bind" ref="control-6" name="control-6"/>
                    </xf:bind>
                </xf:bind>
            </xf:bind>
        </xf:bind>

        <!-- Metadata -->
        <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <metadata>
                <application-name>test</application-name>
                <form-name>test</form-name>
                <title xml:lang="en">Untitled Form</title>
                <description xml:lang="en"/>
                <singleton>false</singleton>
            </metadata>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Attachments -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <attachments>
                <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
            </attachments>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- All form resources -->
        <!-- Don't make readonly by default in case a service modifies the resources -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxf:readonly="false" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <resources>
                <resource xml:lang="en">
                    <control-5>
                        <label/>
                        <hint/>
                    </control-5>
                    <control-6>
                        <label/>
                        <hint/>
                    </control-6>
                    <section-1>
                        <label>Untitled Section</label>
                    </section-1>
                    <control-1>
                        <label/>
                        <hint/>
                        <alert/>
                    </control-1>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Utility instances for services -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <request/>
        </xf:instance>

        <xf:instance id="fr-service-response-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <response/>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" id="mygrid-template">
            <mygrid-iteration t="3">
                <control-5/>
                <control-6/>
            </mygrid-iteration>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:insert ev:event="xforms-model-construct-done" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')" 
                   origin="xxf:get-request-attribute('fr-form-data')"/>
    </xf:model>
</xh:head>
<xh:body>
    <fr:view>
        <fr:body xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
                 xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
                 xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline">;
            <fr:section id="section-1-control" bind="section-1-bind">
                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>
                <fr:grid>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:input id="control-1-control" bind="control-1-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-1/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-1/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                            </xf:input>
                        </xh:td>
                        <xh:td/>
                    </xh:tr>
                </fr:grid>
                <fr:grid id="mygrid-control" bind="mygrid-bind" repeat="content" min="1"
                         template="instance('mygrid-template')">
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:input id="control-5-control" bind="control-5-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-5/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-5/hint"/>

                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                            </xf:input>
                        </xh:td>
                    </xh:tr>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:input id="control-6-control" bind="control-6-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-6/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-6/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                            </xf:input>
                        </xh:td>
                    </xh:tr>
                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
        </fr:body>
    </fr:view>
</xh:body>
```

I then take the contents of the 'fr-form-instance' instance and base64 encode the xml. Then I post the xml using a simple html form:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/test/test/new">
<input type="hidden" name="fr-form-data" value="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"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I look at the 'fr-form-instance' instance in the Orbeon Forms XForms Inspector I see that there is an extra 'mygrid-iteration' iteration tag and the controls are not rendered. Below is the xml as shown in the Forms Inspector:

```
<form>
    <section-1>
        <control-1/>
        <mygrid>
            <mygrid-iteration>
                <mygrid-iteration>
                    <control-5>vijf</control-5>
                    <control-6>zes</control-6>
                </mygrid-iteration>
                <mygrid-iteration>
                    <control-5/>
                    <control-6/>
                </mygrid-iteration>
            </mygrid-iteration>
        </mygrid>
    </section-1>
</form>
```

Notice the extra mygrid-iteration.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is this a bug in Orbeon ? If so, is there a known work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-4.8, Orbeon Forms didn't have an "iteration" element in the XML. You just had `<mygrid>`, and that element itself was repeated. Then 4.8 introduced an iteration element, but, for backward compatibility, that iteration element is removed  when saving data to the database or [sending data](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner.html#send), and added when loading data from the database, or [receiving the data through a POST](http://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner.html#initial-instance-posted-to-the-new-form-page).

In this last case, if you'd like to have that iteration element, then add the `data-format-version=edge` to your request, and Orbeon Forms won't try to add the iteration element.