# data-format version in orbeon view

Tags: java, xml, orbeon

I'm trying to create a form in orbeon forms with a repeated section, but Orbeon generates extra tags around my xml and then gets confused.

I've posted about this problem before:

[Orbeon forms generates duplicate tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945575/orbeon-forms-generates-duplicate-tags/35948197#35948197)

The method described in the answer works great, and makes it possible to save the data to the database with data-format-version=edge. The view in the review page is also correct. I just can't seem to find out how to use this in the 'view' or 'edit' pages, I've tried passing the request parameter data-format-version=edge, both through the embedding api and in the URL of none-embedded orbeon but it does not seem to work.

Any ideas?

Edit:

When viewing a form ( `http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/test/test/view/6fcd81f2612019deab5bb9f4031a92bc1b2b62ec`) with the following xml in the database (xml column of orbeon_form_data):

```
<form>
<section-1>
    <control-1/>
    <mygrid>
            <mygrid-iteration>
                <control-5>vijf</control-5>
                <control-6>zes</control-6>
            </mygrid-iteration>
            <mygrid-iteration>
                <control-5/>
                <control-6/>
            </mygrid-iteration>
    </mygrid>
</section-1>
```

The repeated sections are not shown correctly. When I edit the form (`http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/test/test/edit/6fcd81f2612019deab5bb9f4031a92bc1b2b62ec`). I can see in the form inspector that the xml has changed:

```
<form>
    <section-1>
        <control-1/>
        <mygrid>
            <mygrid-iteration>
                <mygrid-iteration>
                    <control-5>vijf</control-5>
                    <control-6>zes</control-6>
                </mygrid-iteration>
                <mygrid-iteration>
                    <control-5/>
                    <control-6/>
                </mygrid-iteration>
            </mygrid-iteration>
        </mygrid>
    </section-1>
</form>
```

Notice the extra 'mygrid-iteration' tag. I've tried `localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/test/test/edit/6fcd81f2612019deab5bb9f4031a92bc1b2b62ec?data-format-version=edge` and many variations, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Maarten, I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. What is the problem? What behavior do you see, and what behavior did you expect? How can we reproduce it?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have edited my question.

Comment: I added some comments recently to [this issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/635#issuecomment-218835545) to explain the whys and therefores of the change in internal layout. Can you check that and see if that helps you understand?